# Copy multiple files to multiple destination based on text file

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I want to copy list of files specified in text file to list of destination by creating directory. I have one Excel file in which there are 2 columns, source and destination, each source has a destination.

Example Source:

```
\\10.0.0.1\share\abd.nsf
\\20.0.0.1\share\red.nsf
```

Example Dest:

```
\\10.0.0.2\share\abd\
\\10.0.0.2\share\red\
```

Currently I am using below code, but involves n number of lines so it is tedious.

```ps
copy-item "\\10.0.0.1\share\abd.nsf" -destination (New-item "\\10.0.0.2\share\abd\" -Type container -force) -force
copy-item "\\20.0.0.1\share\red.nsf" -destination (New-item "\\10.0.0.2\share\red\" -Type container -force) -force
```

Comment: Not quite sure what the question is here. Are you looking for logic that moves all nsf files into their own folders?

Comment: i am looking for a logic to take backup of resigned user nsf files to user_name folder

Comment: i can copy list of files to common destination, but i want to copy it in username folders

Comment: How do you determine which folder to copy to? Can you show an example from your source file? is it just "\\10.0.0.1\share\abd.nsf"

Comment: I didn't get your question; i have multiple sources like have specified in example, want to copy files to specific destination; each source file will have specific destination,

Comment: So does your text file contain these corresponding source/destinations? I get you are trying to automate this but I need to know what your source data looks like. I know you need `Get-Content` and `ForEach-Object`. Can't answer the question without knowing this.

Comment: i have one excel file in which there are 2 column, source and destination, each source have destination specfied in that file

Comment: Thanks for editing, the question is more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rather simple one. Make your Excel file a 2 column csv where the columns are labelled Source and Destination. You don't have to use those just know that if yours differ that you need to adjust the properties called in the code.

```
$path = "c:\path\to\file.csv"
$jobs = Import-CSV $path
$jobs | ForEach-Object{
    # Check if the target folder exists. If not create it.
    If(-not (Test-Path -PathType Container $_.destination)){New-item "$_.destination" -Type Container -Force}

    # If the source file exists copy it to the destination directory. 
    If(Test-Path $_.Source){Copy-Item $_.Source $_.Destination -Force}
}
```

Creates the destination directory if it does not exist (It is possible the path is still wrong but its better than nothing.). Then copy the file, assuming it also exists, to the destination.

Comment: Thanks @Matt the script is working fine, and this was main requirement

Answer (score 1):

```
$source = get-content c:\source.txt
$destination = get-content c:\destination.txt
$Count= $source.Count
$i = 0

For($i -eq 0;$i -Lt $count; $i++){
Try{new-item -itemtype directory $destination[$i]}
Catch {}
Finally{copy-item $source[$i] $destination[$i]}
}
```

Source and destination in text file  should be in same order