# Copy files from list.txt to new destination (new destination is also in list2.txt)

Tags: powershell

I'm wanting to copy files from 1 location to another.

I have 2 text files - 1 with file paths and 2nd with files paths new location.

Example

**List 1 (old)**

```
C:\temp\file1.txt
C:\temp\file2.txt
```

**List 2 (new desired location)**

```
c:\temp2\file1.txt
c:\temp2\file2.txt
```

Is this possible?

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this is possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy multiple files to multiple destination based on text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34503413/copy-multiple-files-to-multiple-destination-based-on-text-file)

Comment: You might want to read the documentation for [Get-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content), [ForEach-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/ForEach-Object) & [Copy-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Copy-Item) as these will help you with this task.